# JS string / Subsrting method undefine

Tags: javascript, string

I am building login and registration form in NextJS and MongoDB. Users can sign up and then login. I created a profile page. On profile page I want to display user information: name, email, created date.

If I am using `substring()` method I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
```

I was trying `slice()` method and the same `typeError:` as above. Can you tell me why and how to fix it? Thank you.

```js
const [born, setBorn] = useState(user?.user?.createdAt)
console.log(born) // 2023-05-20T04:12:43.952Z
```

I would like to get 2023-05-20

This is my solution:

```js
const created = born.substring(0,10)
console.log(created) // 2023-05-20 here is all good BUT!
```

If I put created to the body. I am getting error as I mentioned above.

```html
<p>Created: {created}</p> // TypeError: Cannot read...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing `born` in state, I would assume that is `undefined` by default (component mount) and gets populated later on. You can verify this by logging the result of `born` before your render your component. Either add an early return:

```
if (!born) {
  return <div>Loading …</div>
}

return (<p>Created: {created}</p>)
```

Or use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) before calling the method:

```js
const created = born?.substring(0,10)
```